# Condense repetitive jquery

Tags: jquery

Could someone show me how to condense this repetitive jquery into a single function? Basically if a radio button is clicked (#pgy_), then the corresponding div (.pgy_) is shown.

```
$('#pgy1').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".pgy1").show();
        } else {
            $(".pgy1").hide();
        }
    });
    $('#pgy2').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".pgy2").show();
        } else {
            $(".pgy2").hide();
        }
    }); 
    $('#pgy3').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".pgy3").show();
        } else {
            $(".pgy3").hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: @steo - yes they absolutely can.

Comment: Start by not using enumerated id's and classes.

Comment: @A.Wolff ["Refactoring"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring)?

Comment: @JasonP Man, i'll write it hundred times, i promise ;)

Comment: @Kevin B They're enumerated because they're generated in a while($i < $var) statement. Is there a different way of doing so?

Comment: @user2558042 Do they need an id at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[id^=pgy]').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("div."+this.id).show();
        } else {
            $("div."+this.id).hide();
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. Now I see how to call a number within a id or class. I'll check your post when I can in a few minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The ID is the same as the class, so just use that, and shorten the hide/show with `toggle()` :

```
$('#pgy1, #pgy2, #pgy3').on('click', function() {
    $('.'+this.id).toggle(this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Traversal might make it better depending on the html, but +1 for `.toggle(this.checked)`

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to move to class names and relative selectors. You may need to adjust, depending on your HTML structure.

```
   $('.btn').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).next('.section').show();
        } else {
             $(this).next('.section').hide();
        }
    });
```

This way you don't need to specify individual elements, you just need to stick to a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
function applySelector(selector){
 $('#'+selector).click(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("."+selector).show();
    } else {
        $("."+selector).hide();
    }
 });
}

applySelector(name_1);
applySelector(name_2);
```